# Combo box in datagrid not updating correctly

Tags: c#, wpf

I am binding a combobox selected index to an integer value (Mode) in my viewmodel.  It seems to work except when I try to change the value in the combobox it will not change the selected index/value.

Xaml:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <ComboBox
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource modeValues}}"
             SelectedIndex="{Binding Mode, Mode=TwoWay}"
          />
    </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

```
public int Mode
    {
        get { return _mode; }
        set
        {
            _mode = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Mode");
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say it will not change the "selected index/value" are you referring to the value in the ViewModel or something else? When you change the ComboBox selection the Mode property on the ViewModel is what will change. Are you expecting different behavior?

Comment: I mean the value in the combo box in the grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed a Cell template and a CellEditingTemplate.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModeText}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource modeValues}}"
                            SelectedIndex="{Binding Mode, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```